# powerline status-line on ubuntu server 14.04 (no gui)

Tags: vim, ubuntu-server, powerline

First of all, is it even possible to get powerline looking like on the image below in a Non-GUI Ubuntu installation?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMohr.png]

So far I've installed it using Vundle, but removed it in favor of the pip installation, but as shown below, I cannot get the proper symbols to show, only the ugly place holder blocks:

[image]

Per the official installation instruction I downloaded and installed the patched fonts in ~/.fonts, after trying "Fontconfig" unsuccessfully. I also refreshed the font cache for the system, and restarted vim, but it stayed the same. The only changes I made on .vimrc were...

```
> set t_Co=256
> rtp+=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/ 
> laststatus=2
```

The instructions I followed:
[askubuntu-powerline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin)
and [powerline-docs](http://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html)

Ubuntu Server 14.04

Vim - 7.4.52

Xterm = 256 color

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is! You need a way to use the patched font in the console. There is only one patched terminal font, Terminus, but I couldn't get it to work.

I discovered [fbterm](https://code.google.com/p/fbterm/), a terminal emulator for the framebuffer that allows you to customize the font and size, even add a background image.

Set up fbterm and add your user to the video group:

```
sudo apt-get install fbterm
sudo usermod -a -G video $USER
```

In your ~/.fbtermrc file change font-name to your favorite font. (use the fc-list command to get the names)

```
font-names=SourceCode Pro for Powerline
font-size=18
```

Launch fbterm

```
fbterm
```

To get full color support set the TERM variable to fbterm before launching vim/tmux

```
TERM=fbterm tmux -2u
```

If the symbols don't line up perfectly, experiment with different fonts and sizes.